# C++: Struct Naming Standards

Tags: c++, struct, naming-conventions, standards

How should I name structs and their variables? This include structs inside objects...

Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to give a complete vision about how you should use Identifiers, that was te purpose only...

Answer (score 4):

Find a style that you like and stick to it. Its as simple as that. I do it like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;
    char baz;

    Foo foo;
};
```

Struct's and classes have their first character capitalized, variables inside don't.

But again, this is my style, find a style that suits you and stick to it. Nothing more to be said.

Comment: I think this is not valid C++ code.

Comment: Styling should be taken more seriously. Getting used to arbitrary styling convention is a serious mistake. It's better to follow the standard styling conventions, eg. search for Google c++ convention.

Answer (score 4):

This is complete list for **Naming conventions** that I consider to be very complete:

- Use US-English for naming identifiers.
- Use Pascal and Camel casing for naming identifiers.
- Do not use Hungarian notation or add any other type identification to identifiers.
- Do not prefix member fields.
- Do not use casing to differentiate identifiers.
- Use abbreviations with care.
- Do not use an underscore in identifiers.
- Name an identifier according to its meaning and not its type.
- Name namespaces according to a well-defined pattern.
- Do not add a suffix to a class or struct name.
- Use a noun or a noun phrase to name a class or struct.
- Prefix interfaces with the letter I.
- Use similar names for the default implementation of an interface.
- Suffix names of attributes with Attribute.
- Do not add an Enum suffix to an enumeration type.
- Use singular names for enumeration types.
- Use a plural name for enumerations representing bitfields.
- Do not use letters that can be mistaken for digits, and vice versa.
- Add EventHandler to delegates related to events.
- Add Callback to delegates related to callback methods.
- Do not add a Callback or similar suffix to callback methods.
- Use a verb (gerund) for naming an event.
- Do not add an Event suffix (or any other type-related suffix) to the name of an event.
- Use an –ing and –ed form to express pre-events and post-events.
- Prefix an event handler with On.
- Suffix exception classes with Exception.
- Do not add code-archive related prefixes to identifiers.
- Name DLL assemblies after their containing namespace.
- Do not add MR building block prefixes to source files.
- Use Pascal casing for naming source files.
- Name the source file to the main class
- Only use the `this`. construction.

This is for C# but also apply for Java/C++. If you want to standarize your code I recommend you to see the [HIGH·INTEGRITY C++ CODING STANDARD MANUAL](http://www.codingstandard.com/HICPPCM/index.html).

For **casing identifiers** you should do it as follow:

- Class, Struct (Pascal, eg: AppDomain)
- Enum type (Pascal, eg: ErrorLevel)
- Enum values (Pascal, eg: FatalError)
- Event (Pascal, eg: ValueChange)
- Exception class Pascal, eg: WebException)
- Field (camel, eg: listItem)
- Const Field   Pascal, eg: MaximumItems)
- Read-only Static Field  Pascal, eg: RedValue)
- Interface (Pascal, eg: IDisposable)
- Method (Pascal, eg: ToString)
- Namespace (Pascal, eg: System.Drawing)
- Parameter (camel, eg: typeName)
- Property (Pascal, eg: BackColor)

Comment: You shoul add comments about whay you're down-voting. So I can understand whats wrong with this.

Comment: c'mon, that is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: camel case is certainly not standardised.

Comment: I did not vote up or down, but this is my feedback: the question asks about structs, whereas your answer aims to provide a complete list, which is good and bad -- covers more cases but readers can get lost. So it would be good if you can highlight the parts related to structs, either in the list or summarize this at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Harmonise your style with the people around you -- within reason, it doesn't matter which naming scheme you use for structs and variables, provided everyone on your team is doing a consistent thing.

Personally, I name structs like this:

`FunkyContainer`

And variables like this:

`ratherUsefulVariable`

But you have to adapt what you do to fit the house style, or you'll ruin the consistency of your team's code.

As a side note, you don't have "structs inside objects" -- you can have nested structs, which are structs inside structs, but that's not the same thing. An object is an *instance* of a struct, not the struct itself. (Objects can also be instances of classes, obviously, but that's irrelevant for the purpose of making the distinction here.)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, by "object" I meant an instance of a class.

Comment: @Jay: Same comment applies there -- you don't have nested structs inside *objects*, you have nested structs inside *classes*.

Answer (score 1):

Any naming standard I'm familiar with are for the platform, library, etc. For example, Windows SDK has a standard, the CRT has a standard, and MFC has a standard.

I've seen no standard for C++. Perhaps you should look at what naming conventions others are using on your particular platform.

Comment: I'm following this standard for the most part: http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/CppCodingStandard.html

Comment: Then that's your answer. In the end, all that matters is that you and the people you work with are comfortable with the naming standards used.

Comment: That standard doesn't talk about structs, so that is why I asked the question.